# Determining when a AsyncTask has Completed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that I kick off from one Activity. It saves some data to sqlite database and can take a few seconds to do. I have set up a standard progress bar within onPreExecute() and dismissing it within onPostExecute() and doing some work in the doInBackground(Void... arg0).

What I need once the task has been completed to return to the activity and finish() it. Trouble is I cannot seem to work out how to wait for AsyncTask to complete. I can work out the status but that is not helping me.

```
    public class UpdateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progress.setMessage("Loading ...");
            progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
          // Do work
         return true;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
             progress.dismiss();

          }
}
```

What do I need to do to the main activity to call finish() once it has completed. Thanks for your time

UPDATE
Excute the task by

```
UpdateAsyncTask task = new UpdateAsyncTask(context);

                task.setCallbackActivity(this);

                task.execute();
```

UPDATE 2
The aynctask is a seperate task as I wish to re-use it

Comment: onPostExecute() happens when the task is finished. It is designed this way with it own handler so you should just use that to complete whatever task you are trying to complete.

Comment: I may not have understood your question... are you trying to finish the activity after the task completes?

Comment: yes. The Main Activity calls the AsyncTask and once it is completed I want to call finish() on the activity

Comment: As Aviel has said just call finish() from onPostExecute().

Comment: Is your dialog being dismissed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement callback with an interface as follows :

Interface :

```
public interface CallbackActivity {
     public void activityCallback();
}
```

Implement this interface in activity :

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements CallbackActivity{ 
      @Override
      public void activityCallback(){
         finish();
      }
}
```

Your updateAsyncTask :

```
public class UpdateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
      private CallbackActivity mCallback = null;
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
           progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
           progress.setMessage("Loading ...");
           progress.show();
      }

      @Override
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Do work
           return true;

      }

      protected void onPostExecute() {
         progress.dismiss();
         if(this.mCallback != null) { this.mCallback.activityCallback(); }
      }

      public void setCallbackActivity(CallbackActivity ca) {
         this.mCallback = ca;
      }

}
```

Your UpdateAsyncTask is entirely decoupling of a specific activity and you can use it anywhere as you want (but you need to set the callback)... If it's not needed use an inner class in the activity is more easy

EDIT : You can add in the AsyncTask constructor an argument to pass the callback directly (less code)

Comment: onPostExecute() runs on the (Main)UI thread, it is the whole point of using an asynctask. Why would you add a callback? Doesn't that seem redundant?

Comment: Well it it progress but just sits there now and not complete. Guess its how I am excuting it. see update

Comment: Have you add : "if(this.mCallback != null) { this.mCallback.activityCallback(); }" in your onPostExecute ?

Comment: put your activity and update Async task code... I have tested it.  it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
public class UpdateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
            ProgressDialog(context) progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progress.setMessage("Loading ...");
            progress.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
          // Do work
         return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        progress.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
}
```

This should be nested in your activity class and executed like this:

```
new UpdateAsyncTask().execute();
```

Comment: Does not let me add finish() here without adding a new method

Comment: Is this class currently nested in an activity class? That is how I would typically use an asynctask...

Comment: No, it is a seperate class as I will be wanting to use it again for a different acvtivity

Comment: That is likely your problem... if you want it to work that way you should probably look into using a handler with a new thread instead of using an asynctask improperly. According to the documentation "AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used."  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute()` happens on the main thread (your UI) so you can just call `finish()` from `onPostExecute()` if your `AsyncTask` is an inner class of the activity, or send the context and finish the activity with `context.finish()`. Another option is to call from `onPostExecute()` to a method in your activity class that runs `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean finish it? you mean the activity that calls the AsyncTask?
you can finish it inside your AsyncTask.
All you need is to pass the context from your activity class to the AsyncTask.

```
private Context context;
protected Boolean doInBackground(Context c) {
      context=c;
     return true;
}
protected void onPostExecute() {
         progress.dismiss();
    ((Activity)context).finish();
}
```